# Grouping every piece of conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, compiler-construction

How can i group every piece of conditional stmt inside an if parenthesis. Say i have a text from my contenteditable div. This is more than Syntax Highlighting, i'll use the wrap text for processing later in the code.

```
text = if ( x==1 && (x>2 || (!x>2 || x<=0)) )
```

I would like them to be group accordingly and stored in an array like this

```
condFragment[0]=('x==1 && (x>2 || (!x>2 || x<=0))');
condFragment[1]=('x==1');
condFragment[2]=('(x>2 || (!x>2 || x<=0))');
condFragment[3]=('x>2');
condFragment[4]=('(!x>2 || x<=0)');
condFragment[5]=('!x>2');
condFragment[6]=('x>2');
condFragment[7]=('x<=0');
```

From this:

```
<div id="board">
     <div>int main(){</div>
     <div></div>
     <div>if(x==1 && !x>2)</div>
     <div>statement;</div>
     <div>while(!x>5){</div>
     <div>statement;}</div>
     <div>}</div>
</div>
```

This is what i want to achieve from using `condFragment` content

```
<div id="board">
     <div>int main(){</div>
     <div></div>
     <div>
     if(<span class="frag"><span class="frag">x==1</span> && 
     <span class="frag">!<span class="frag">x>2</span></span></span>)
     </div>
     <div>statement;</div>
     <div>while(!x>5){</div>
     <div>statement;}</div>
     <div>}</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

MY idea in solving this based on the `text` is:

1. search for && || ! from left to right
2. if found one get indexOF( && or || or !)
3. if the left side of the found && is surrounded by paren slice it from there up to index of &&
4. if right side of && is an open paren, slice it after && up to the 1st found 2nd )

But how do i know that those are the place where i should slice?

Comment: Offtopic: There are many syntax highlighters, do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @undefined, more than syntax highlighting, i will use the wrap text for evaluation later

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you are better off having a full javascript parser.

Take a look at https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS.

This project includes a full JS parser.

Comment: dont know how to use github, newbie here

Comment: It is going to take far less time and effort to learn how to use github and existing libraries than trying to create your own parser. It might take you a year and it could be buggy, too. On the other hand, UglifyJS is already proven to be working really well by millions.